Error Plotting Data with mplfinance: 'x and y must be the same size' having issues Adding VWAP and Bands
I need to plot vwap and stock buy signals on a chart. So far ive had no issues exporting the .csv with the vwap calculation applied to it, but plotting it is another issue. I keep getting this persistent error that x and y must be the same size.
Here's my code for the plotter:
import pandas as pd
import mplfinance as mpf
import os


def plot_data_with_signals(csv_file):
    try:
        # Check if file exists
        if not os.path.exists(csv_file):
            raise FileNotFoundError(f"File not found: {csv_file}")

        # Load the data from the CSV
        df = pd.read_csv(csv_file, parse_dates=True, index_col="Date")

        if df.empty:
            print("No data to plot.")
            return

        # Ensure data columns are named correctly for mplfinance
        df.rename(columns={
            'Open': 'Open',
            'High': 'High',
            'Low': 'Low',
            'Close': 'Close',
            'Volume': 'Volume'
        }, inplace=True)

        # Ensure the index is properly set to 'Date'
        df.index.name = 'Date'

        # Create additional plot elements for VWAP, bands, and buy signals
        apds = []

        if 'vwap' in df.columns:
            apds.append(mpf.make_addplot(df['vwap'], color='blue', linestyle='--', secondary_y=False))
        if 'upper_band' in df.columns and 'lower_band' in df.columns:
            apds.append(mpf.make_addplot(df['upper_band'], color='red', linestyle='--', secondary_y=False))
            apds.append(mpf.make_addplot(df['lower_band'], color='green', linestyle='--', secondary_y=False))
        if 'buy_signal' in df.columns:
            # Create scatter plot for buy signals
            buy_signals = df[df['buy_signal'] == 1]
            if not buy_signals.empty:
                apds.append(mpf.make_addplot(buy_signals['Close'], type='scatter', markersize=100, color='magenta',
                                             secondary_y=False))

        # Plotting data using mplfinance
        mpf.plot(df, type='candle', style='charles', title='SPY 5-Minute Interval Candlestick Chart',
                 ylabel='Price', volume=True, addplot=apds)

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error plotting data. Something went wrong: {e}")


# Example usage
plot_data_with_signals("spy_data/spy_data_5m_vwap_bands_signals.csv")  # Update with the path to CSV file


I've tried checking for missing values and things many times over.
Any help is appreciated

Can you please provide also the error message?

The length of the data in your mpf.makeaddplot() calls must be same as the length of the data in your mpf.plot() call, that is:
whatever the value of len(df) is, the following values should be identical:
len(df['vwap'])
len(df['upper_band'])
len(df['lower_band'])
len(buy_signals['Close'])

Add some print statements, or take a look in the debugger to see which is the culprit.  You haven't provided data or the exact error message so difficult to say which one is the problem.
If I were to guess, I'd say buy_signals only because that's a common one for people to mess up.  Typically buy signals are not at every point, which means that, in order for the data to be the same length as len(df) then you will have to fill buy_signals with float('nan') values where there are no signals.  You can see this being done in cell In [7]: and cell In [12]: in the addplot notebook example here: https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/examples/addplot.ipynb
